# YII - Adding error code in form validation

Tags: json, web-services, validation, error-handling, yii

I have a web-service and want to send a custom error-code and string in case form validation fails. We can specify error 'message' in form validation rules, but I want to add a numerical error code, that I can use later to get a text string. Extending CValidator is not an option as I want to use standard validators.

Ideally, I would like something like this in my rules() function.

```
    array('page',  'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true, 'min' => 1, 'message' => '{attribute} is invalid', 'code' => 10079),
```

Later I return a JSON block like

```
    {
            'code': 10079,
            'message' : 'page is invalid'
    }
```

I am thinking of attaching a behavior to validators, but not quite able to figure out a way to make it work. Is there any other yii-way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

instead of message , you just return the error code as message and on the view page just call a function to retrieve the appropriate error message.

provide $form->error(); as parameter to get errorMessage on the view page.